# Unparseable date: "2018-08-02T14:24:40.040353"

Tags: java, date, datetime, parsing, date-format

I am trying to parse a DateTime from C# to Java. Here is what comes as string from the java call `"2018-08-02T14:24:40.040353"`. When I try to parse it, I get the following error `Unparseable date: "2018-08-02T14:24:40.040353"`

Here is the method for parsing the date

```
public static String dateFormater(String dateFromJSON, String 
    expectedFormat, String oldFormat) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(oldFormat);
    Date date = null;
    String convertedDate = null;
    try {
        date = dateFormat.parse(dateFromJSON);
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new 
        SimpleDateFormat(expectedFormat);
        convertedDate = simpleDateFormat.format(date);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return convertedDate;
}
```

Comment: What are the parameters you're using in the function call? oldFormat should look something like "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: You are missing the most important information - the precise value of `oldFormat`

Comment: FYI: You are using terrible old date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your date look like a [`ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME), If you are using Java8 you can use [java.time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) and use the default format of [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) like this :

```
String dateString = "2018-08-02T14:24:40.040353";
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(dateString);
```

> ldt.toString():
>
> 2018-08-02T14:24:40.040353

Comment: Even if you are using Java 6, you can use a backport of JSR-310. +1

Comment: Thank you @PeterLawrey new thing for me

Comment: Yes @PeterLawrey I use this library in my old projects, it is really helpful

Comment: Does it have any alternative because i am using it in android and the Call requires API level 26

Comment: @KristiyanGergov yes al already mentioned by PeterLawrey you can use https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP library in your project, it has almost every thing from java.time

Comment: More helpful details in [this question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Comment: Thank you @OleV.V. this should be the answer of that OP's comment

Comment: @KristiyanGergov take a look at the link that Ole V.V. share it can gives you a good details [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project)